# average of an inequality

Tags: inequality, arithmetic

what is the result of $<1 + <1$? ;
$<1 + <1 = <2$? or <1 + <1 = <1?

Now what is that number divided by 2?
Either we have:
<2 / 2 = <1 or 
<1 / 2 = <0.5

Comment: What do you mean by "<1"?

Comment: What does "<1" mean? Is it "some number less than 1"?

Comment: Yes it means that the number is something less than one.

Comment: We have a product and make a 1:10 dilution. (10 mL into 90mL) We plate 1 mL in duplicate by spread plate method but find no growth on the two plates. 
Our specification is NMT 100 cfu/mL. 
How do we report our final results? 
We had a recent audit by Lachman and he said that since we plate in duplicate that we should be reporting <5 and not <10. 
Is this <5 cfu/mL (because we plated in duplicate) or <10 cfu/mL based on the dilution.

Comment: each plate has <1 cfu. Because we plated twice we want to average the less than value. I am not even sure if that is the right method here.

Comment: I have looked all over the place Microbiology network, food microbiology, lucia klontz has a book on microbiology and all are pointing to the final answer as <10 but what is the justification for <5?

Answer (score 1):

I have to infer that by "$<1$" you mean the *set* of all real numbers less than $1$.  That's more commonly written as the open interval $(-\infty,1)$.  If $A$ and $B$ are sets, then there is a well-defined set addition operation, defined by
$$
A + B = \left\{a+b \mid a \in A,\ b\in B\right\}
$$

If $x < 1$ and $y < 1$, then $x+y < 2$.  This tells us that $(-\infty,1) + (-\infty,1) \subseteq (-\infty,2)$.  Moreover, if $z < 2$, then $z/2 < 1$, and since $z = z/2 + z/2$, we know $(-\infty,2) \subseteq (-\infty,1) + (-\infty,1)$.  Taking the two together, we have
$$
    (-\infty,1) + (\infty,1) = (-\infty,2)
$$
or "$\mathop{<}1 + \mathop{<}1 = \mathop{<}2$" as you wrote it.

Similarly, we can define for a set $A$ and number $\alpha$ the set
$$
    \alpha A = \left\{\alpha a \mid a \in A\right\}
$$
It's not hard to show that
$$
    \frac{1}{2}(-\infty,2) = (-\infty,1)
$$

But to be less formal, and reading your whole question, it seems you want to know what assumptions you can make about the average of two numbers if you know their bounds.  If they are both less than one, then yes, their average is less than one.

Comment: Thank you, your answer makes a lot of sense. I am uncertain about the last comment about if we are certain both are less than one it would be less than one.

Comment: Let's assume A = < 1 and B = <1. Let's assume we know that A's value is 0.4 and B's value is 0.3. each value in itself has a value of less than one and the sum of those values is <1.

Comment: Let's assume A = < 1 and B = <1. Let's assume we know that A's value is 0.7 and B's value is 0.9 each value in itself has a value of less than one however the sum of those values is <2 not <1.

Comment: @Heather: If both are less than one, their **average** must be less than one, but their **sum** must be less than two.

Answer (score 0):

I will take the question to mean this: If all we know about two number is that they are both less then $1$, then what can we conclude about their sum?

In the first place, it is less than $2$.

The harder question, is whether we can conclude any more than that.  And the answer to that is: no.  The reason is this: Suppose $y<2$.  Then $y/2 < 1$.  So add $y/2$ to itself and get $y$.  In other words, any number at all that is less than $2$ can be the sum of two numbers less than $1$.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am still stuck in a quandary if it is in fact <1 or <2. Hm.

Answer (score 0):

Basic property of inequalities: if $a<b$ and $c<d$ then $a+b<c+d$. Why? Cause when adding $c$ to the left hand side (LHS) and $d$ to the right hand side (RHS), the increment on the LHS is smaller than the increment on the RHS, so the inequality is preserved.